# How to Convert Latex pdf to word without change style?

Tags: convert

I've tried convert my latex to word. But the word always have some different with pdf Latex. Such as font and another more

Comment: You will always have different formatting in Word. You can only hope that at least  the logical structure of the document (sections, tables, math, lists, etc.) are preserved. You should also post what you had tried ready - document sample, tools you used, what you didn't like. Right now it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: If you want a LaTeX-y font in Word, see http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern

Comment: Surely you've ever translated some text. Often a word does not have an exact equivalent in the other language, or  the literal translation does not have a correct meaning in the other language. Therefore, automatic translations are always of  poor quality. Well, with the conversion of document formats, especially from LateX to Word, the same thing happen.